# when socketChannel.read(BUFFER) will return 0

Tags: java, sockets, socketchannel

I have a server which reads from the `SocketChannel` like below:

```
private void readDataFromSocket(SocketChannel socketChannel) throws IOException {            
        BUFFER.clear();
        int count = 0;
        while ((count = socketChannel.read(BUFFER)) > 0) {
            BUFFER.flip();
            int limit = BUFFER.limit();
            while (limit > 0) {
                System.out.print((char) BUFFER.get());
                limit--;
            }                
        }            
        if (count < 0) {
            System.out.println("closing the socket!!!");
            socketChannel.close();
        }
    }
```

And below is the client where client writes to the `SocketChannel`:

```
private void write(String str, SocketChannel channel) throws IOException{
        byte[] b = str.getBytes();
        buffer.clear();
        buffer.put(b);
        buffer.flip();
        while(buffer.hasRemaining()){
            channel.write(buffer);
        }
    }
```

So my question:

- when exactly in the server code the `count` value will be 0 (  `while ((count = socketChannel.read(BUFFER)) > 0)`)?
- is it possible that the `count` will be 0 if the server has read half of the message that client has sent i.e.
  Suppose client wrote:  `stack overflow`, is it possible that in the server `count` will be 0 after reading `stack` i.e. half of the message that the client has sent (think that the message can be of 1MB size)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using blocking mode, you will always get at least 1 byte.  Note: you might only get 1 byte, it doesn't read "messages".

When using non-blocking mode, you will get 0 most of the time, in fact whenever there is not a packet waiting for you.

In TCP, data is sent in packets, not messages.  This means if you send 1 MB, most likely it will be broken into packets of your MTU size e.g. ~1500 bytes.  If you read this socket, you will most likely see blocks of this size or a multiple if multiple packets came in since the last read.  You will never see part of a packet, unless you read less than the available data. e.g. if 1500 bytes is waiting and you read just 8 bytes, you get part of that packet.

Comment: Than how will i know that server has read a complete message which was sent from client?

Comment: @Trying The most common way is to send the length first e.g. 4-byte int value.  When you have read that much, you have a whole message. Note: you can read multiple messages in one read, and possibly a bit of the next message. You have to handle multiple messages and partial reads.  Have a look at ByteBuffer.compact() which can be useful.

Comment: Can't i use request response paradigm. Suppose client send something than waits for response (suppose simply a char like `:`) than it will again sent something else. Client will sent `\r\n` after each message.  will it not fix all the issues as i know what is the end of the message in server and client will wait till it finds response from server. Am i correct?

Comment: @Trying Correct, you can use a text terminator instead.  However if you are going to this perhaps using a BufferedReader will be much simpler.